# How to send post data using CURL to mailchimp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

In my app i want to post the data in my **mailchimp** account i have created and **mailchimp** id and get `API KEY`. Now I want to post data on **mailchimp** using php `CURL` method when i send the data it shows an error like

error page
[image]

post data parameters

[image]

Note : while fetching data using `CURL` it is perfectly fine.

How can i solve this issue any body help.

this is my method

```
public function callAPI($method, $url, $data=null)
{
   $curl = curl_init();
    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
            break;
            default:
            if($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
        }
        $headers = array(  
            "Authorization: Basic b3dhaXNfdGFhcnVmZjo5MzM1M" 
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl, 
        [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers, 
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url.'?apikey=this is api key'
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
}
```

this is store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $data_array = '
    {
        "id": "PRS08", 
        "title": "108", 
        "handle": "108", 
        "url": "http://boksha.eshmar.com/product/hoodie-kaftan-1", 
        "description": "", 
        "type": "Abaya",
        "vendor": "TALAR NINA", 
        "image_url": "http://boksha.eshmar.com/uploads/products/140/images/cropped/1512195907.png", 
        "variants": 
        [
        {
            "id": "PROD003A", 
            "title": "variants 1", 
            "url": "", 
            "sku": "", 
            "price": 280, 
            "inventory_quantity": 100, 
            "image_url": "http://boksha.eshmar.com/uploads/products/140/images/cropped/1512195907.png", 
            "backorders": "0", 
            "visibility": "visible", 
            "created_at": "2016-02-08T13:06:44+00:00", 
            "updated_at": "2016-02-08T13:06:44+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "PROD003B", 
            "title": "variants 2", 
            "url": "", 
            "sku": "", 
            "price": 280, 
            "inventory_quantity": 99, 
            "image_url": "http://boksha.eshmar.com/uploads/products/140/images/cropped/1512195907.png",
             "backorders": "0", 
             "visibility": "true", 
             "created_at": "2016-02-08T22:14:37+00:00", 
             "updated_at": "2016-02-08T22:22:38+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }';
    $url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/";
    $data = $this->callAPI('POST', $url, $data_array);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: Could you try curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-how-to-make-curl-http-request-example

Comment: i did it but got same error

Comment: What are the parameters the post is expecting?

Comment: Try this
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, ");

Comment: see above image for parameters and I have used CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST but not work

Comment: for post ?? u used for put

Comment: not i am using post for post data

Comment: i doubt ur url is not correct, could you share which url you are accessing in the documentation of the mail chimp api

Comment: i am using this url (https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/) it is working on postman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186957/discussion-between-jigs1212-and-shahid-hussain).

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that could be an issue.

First - Add a content type to your headers.  It looks like you are trying to post a json string so it makes sense that your header would declare that.

```
$headers = array(  
 'Authorization: Basic b3dhaXNfdGFhcnVmZjo5MzM1M',
 'Content-Type: application/json' //Addded the content type as json.
 );
```

Secondly - Your json string you are sending is not valid json.  You need to remove the comma off the last element in the string.

```
$data_array = '
        {
            "id": "PRS08", 
            "title": "Php Curl", 
            "name": "Shahid Hussain", 
            "url": "http://fstnv.com", 
            "description": "This is test data"
        }'; //Removed the comma after last element.  Otherwise the json is invalid.
```

See if that helps you.

Comment: this not work please see the $data_array i have updated right parameters

Comment: What parameters does the post expect?

Comment: Actually no where in your code do you mention the parameters.  The API is expecting something like: example.com?id=123&name='Ted'.  id and name are parameters.  What is your API expecting from you?

Comment: all the  parameters has given in $data_array variable id , title and handle etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the end point, 
the endpoint is not correct.

the end point should be as follows according to your postman code

`https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0//ecommerce/stores/store_001/products`

Update the same.